# Different binary tree's definitions in Haskell: which wins?

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I was used to the following `Tree` definition:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

until I ran into this one somewhere:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

which makes me wonder about Haskell idioms.

Since `Leaf a` is just `Node a Empty Empty`, should this constructor exist? We could remove `Empty` as well, using a unique constructor like

```
Tree (Maybe (a, (Tree a), (Tree a)))
```

or something like that.

The second definition I wrote is the "most expanded" one and the first is halfway between it and the last one. What's practically and theorically the best one? In other words, what about performance and data-types' design?

Comment: The third, `Tree (Maybe a (Tree a) (Tree a))` doesn't compile. Did you mean `Tree (Maybe (a, Tree a, Tree a))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want idiomatic Haskell, use the first definition, because then you have less constructors to pattern-match against.

If you have huge binary trees with a lot of leaves, use the second definition if you want to save about 16 bytes (The extra `Tree a`-pointers) of memory per leaf (depends heavily on which platform/compiler you're using how much memory is saved).

The third alternative that you present is technically a valid representation (assuming that you meant `Tree (Maybe (a, Tree a, Tree a))`, but it is very tedious to work with.

Comment: I see, so the second definition can use less memory but the first can be faster, right? What about the third?
Would it be a good idea to add as well two constructors: `NodeOne a (Tree a)` to save 8 bytes in case of `Node a (Tree a) Empty`?

Comment: You have to benchmark to see how many specialized constructors you might need; maybe the cost of having 4 constructors is too high, and some compilers will use "tagged unions" for ADTs, making all of them use the same amount of memory. The third version is both more complex and less efficient, however. But most of the time, you won't have really huge binary trees, so all of this shouldn't matter. If you want to store massive amounts of integers in a tree, you should look at using some kind of prefix trees instead.

Answer (score 6):

dflemstr's answer is spot on, but I thought I'd add two remarks (that can't be accommodated by a comment to the original answer).

First, by the same logic that the second definition can save memory, a similar argument can be made for this one:

```
data Tree a = Empty 
            | Leaf a 
            | LeftOnly a (Tree a) 
            | RightOnly a (Tree a) 
            | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Whether this actually matters depends on your application.

The second and more important remark is that if you avoid using data constructors directly, you can abstract away from these implementation choices.  For example, equivalent `foldTree` functions can be written for any of these types.  For the shorter type you do it like this:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

foldTree :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f z Empty = z
foldTree f z (Node v l r) = f v (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldTree f z
```

And for the longer one you can write it like this:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

foldTree :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f z Empty = z
foldTree f z (Leaf v) = f v z z
foldTree f z (Node v l r) = f v (subfold l) (subfold r)
    where subfold = foldTree f z
```

The same can be done for your `Maybe`-based alternative or for my five-constructor alternative.  Also, this technique can be applied to whatever other generic functions on trees that you need.  (In fact, a lot of these functions can be written in terms of `foldTree`, so most of it falls out of the definitions above.)

Comment: Your five-constructor one looks unlikely. Far more reasonable, I think, would be to have data Tree a = Empty | NETree a  and data NETree a = Branch a (NETree a) (NETree a) | LeftOnly a (NETree a) |RightOnly a (NETree a) | Leaf a. Yes, this takes a tiny bit more time to get into, but it enforces the constraints the names suggest.